# Type check between class and object literal in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

in TypeScript, an object literal can be assigned to a class typed variable if that object provides all properties and methods that the class needs.

```
class MyClass {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

// Compiler won't complain
const instance: MyClass = { a: 1, b: '' };

// Compiler won't complain if I assign an object with more properties
const literal = { a: 1, b: '', c: false };
const instance2: MyClass = literal;
```

What I want to do here is to prevent this kind of assignment based on two reasons:

1. `instance instanceof MyClass` should be true;
2. I can assign an object with more properties (see above).

In this way, TypeScript class works more like an interface. Is there a way I can prevent this?

Comment: Based on the rest of the question, I'm guessing in point #2 you meant something more like "I *don't want to allow* assigning an object with more properties"?

Comment: @ecraig12345 Yes, you are completely right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), what you're observing seems to be the expected behavior:

> Type compatibility in TypeScript is based on structural subtyping. Structural typing is a way of relating types *based solely on their members.*

So if two types have the same structure, it's intended that objects of those types can be assigned to each other.

There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#29063](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29063) asking for some way to distinguish class instance types from structurally identical object types, but for now it's not part of the language.

### Workaround: private members

Once you start adding private members to a class (which you'd almost always do in practice), the type checking works much closer to how you want.

```
class MyClass {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  private c: number;
}

// "Property 'c' is missing in type '{ a: number; b: string; }' but required in type 'MyClass'."
const instance: MyClass = { a: 1, b: '' };

// "Property 'c' is private in type 'MyClass' but not in type '{ a: number; b: string; c: number; }'"
const literal: MyClass = { a: 1, b: '', c: 3 };

class OtherClass {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  private c: number;
}

// "Types have separate declarations of a private property 'c'"
const otherClass: MyClass = new OtherClass();
```

Comment: This piece of doc is exactly what I want to see. Thanks. One more question: if I don't want to introduce private fields, then I can't rely on instanceof, right?

Comment: [instanceof is is a plain JS operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof), so it will work how you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly but what I infer from your code is that.

In your second assignment, the variable `literal` is not defined as the type `MyClass`

```
const literal = { a: 1, b: '', c: false };
```

So, you are just trying to create a const variable with some values.

Comment: Hi. Sorry I forgot one line of code and just edited (see above). What I want to say is, in case of "const literal: MyClass = {a: 1, b:'' ,c: false}", compiler will complain that c is unknown. But in the way above compiler won't complain and as a result, I assign an object with more properties to the class type variable.