# Compare two objects of different types

Tags: typescript, jasmine

I'm trying to write a test for a function that takes an object and filters out only the properties I want, e.g:

```
const srcObj = {
 singleString: 'this',
 extraString: 'what?',
 singleNumber: 4,
 extraNumber: 0,
 singleObject: {
   prop: 'this'
 },
 extraObject: {
   nope: 'what is this'
  }
};
```

becomes

```
const expected: Model = {
  singleString: 'this',
  singleNumber: 4,
  singleObject: {
    prop: 'this'
  }
};
```

When I try to run the test

```
const modelObj = new Model()
const result = filterFunction(srcObj, modelObj)
expect(result).toEqual(expected)
```

I get the error

```
    Expected object to be a kind of Object, but was Model({ singleString: 'this', singleNumber: 4, singleObject: Object({  }) }).
```

I've tried casting srcObj to `Model` in the variable declaration, (which I feel is kinda defeating the purpose), casting both objects to the same in the expect statement (i.e. `expect(result as Model).toEqual(expected as Model)`, and casting them both as `any` (`expect(result as any).toEqual(expected as any)`)

I'm sure there's a relatively minor thing I'm missing to get this test to work, but I'm not sure what it is.

**Edit**

my `filterfunction`:

```
filterFunction(srcObj: any, destObj: any): any {
        var lSrcKeys: string[] = Object.keys(srcObj);
        var lDestKeys: string[] = Object.keys(destObj);
        var lSrcKeyFound: string = '';
        var lKeyType: string = '';
        var lKeyArrayType: string = '';

        lDestKeys.forEach((lDestKey) => {
            lSrcKeyFound = '';

            lSrcKeys.forEach((lSrcKey) => {
                if (lSrcKey.toLowerCase() === lDestKey.toLowerCase()) {
                    lSrcKeyFound = lSrcKey;
                }
            });

            if (lSrcKeyFound !== '') {
                lKeyType = Object.prototype.toString.call(srcObj[lSrcKeyFound]);

                if (lKeyType === '[object Array]' && srcObj[lSrcKeyFound].length) {
                    lKeyArrayType = Object.prototype.toString.call(srcObj[lSrcKeyFound][0]);

                    if (lKeyArrayType === '[object Object]') {
                        for (var i = 0; i < srcObj[lSrcKeyFound].length; i++) {
                            var lSrcArrayItem: any = srcObj[lSrcKeyFound][i];

                            destObj[lDestKey].push(ModelUtil.filterFunction(lSrcArrayItem, null));
                        }
                    } else {
                        destObj[lDestKey] = srcObj[lSrcKeyFound];
                    }
                } else if (lKeyType === '[object Object]') {
                    ModelUtil.filterFunction(srcObj[lSrcKeyFound], destObj[lDestKey]);
                } else {
                    destObj[lDestKey] = srcObj[lSrcKeyFound];
                }
            }
        });
        return destObj;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the code for `filterFunction`?

Comment: It's a little bit of a mess. I'm actually trying to write the test so I have something to check against when I refactor. I'll see what I can do though.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have "casting" as most people mean it; it has [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), which have zero runtime effect.  If your issue is at runtime and not at compile time, no amount of using `as` will change that.

Comment: I'm also using Karma as my test runner, if that's helpful to anyone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type check between class and object literal in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54645400/type-check-between-class-and-object-literal-in-typescript?rq=1)

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, I figured I wouldn't have to worry about types since I would essentially be comparing two objects. However, the error tells me that one isn't an object, but a `Model` (one of my classes ). So now I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: `expect(obj1).toEqual(obj2)` probably cares if `obj1` and `obj2` were made by different constructors, whereas TypeScript doesn't care about how an object was constructed when determining compatibility.  Basically this isn't a TypeScript issue, but a JavaScript issue.

Comment: @jcalz This is what the Jasmine docs say about `toEqual`: "expect the actual value to be equal to the expected, using deep equality comparison". Is this what you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's jasmine checking the constructors not a typescript issue

You can destructure to get them to the same constructor

```
expect({...objOfTypeA}).toEqual({...objOfTypeB});
```

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/598#issuecomment-340284189